# How can I compare bundle identifier to the provisioning profile

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-devops, xamarin.ios, info.plist

I am trying to build my Xamarin.Forms iOS application on Azure DevOps. The task fails with this error:

> Info.plist : error : Project bundle identifier 'com.companyname.Companyname' does not match specified provisioning profile '45df6006-d521-44ac-b8tt-cd6884c22fd7'

In the provisioning profile, I see this application-identifier:

> MC6JH2Y2UQ.com.companyname.com.companyname.Companyname

Can you tell how the bundle identifier should correspond to the provisioning profile, and what I should change to fix it?

Comment: This Article will help https://popovskas.com/2020/10/25/build-xamarin-ios-app-with-azure-devops/

Comment: it looks like you need to fix your provisioning profile in the Apple dev portal

Comment: @Jason I have recreated it already several times. To fix it, I need to know what is wrong with it.

Comment: "companyname" is in there three times - that seems pretty obvious?  Without knowing exactly how you are setting up your profiles and other identifiers its difficult to say what exactly is wrong.

Comment: @Jason For me it was not that obvious, because that ID was generated, so I did not think I could control it. Should I just change the ID in the text editor, and upload to the Azure Pipeline? But then Apple will not recognize it, I suppose? And should the ID be MC6JH2Y2UQ.com.companyname.Companyname?

Comment: you need to fix the app identifier in the Apple dev portal and then regenerate the provisioning profile

Comment: @Jason Hmm, I tried to edit it in "All Identifiers", but there only the description is editable, and when I change it, it says, "Invalid description"...

Comment: then add a new one that is correct

Comment: @Jason I tried to create new ID, but when I enter com-companyname-Companyname (previously it was com-companyname-com-companyname-Companyname), it says again, "Invalid description" :(

Comment: under description, it clearly says `You cannot use special characters such as @, &, *, ', ", -, .`.   The bundle id should generally be formatted `com.company.appname` for an explicit ID

Comment: @Jason Sorry, but I have tried that format, and it said "Invalid description".

Comment: I suggest you contact Apple support or use their forums.  Without knowing exactly what you are entering it's impossible to say what the problem is.  I just created a test ID and didn't have any problems

Comment: @Jason I can create the bundle ID in the format you suggested. I guess, the description can be anything? I will try that and give and update.

Comment: a description is just that, a description.  It's not used for anything other than labeling AFAIK

Comment: @Jason It worked, thank you very much. If you make it an answer, I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new AppID using the bundle format `com.company.appname` (and use the same bundle ID in your iOS project) and generate a provisioning profile to go with it.